# transform do syntax to >>= with ((->) r) monad

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

On the page http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_Notation, there's a very handy way to transform the do syntax with binding to the functional form (I mean, using >>=). It works well for quite a few case, until I encountered a piece of code involving functions as monad ((->) r)

The code is

```
addStuff :: Int -> Int  
addStuff = do  
    a <- (*2)  
    b <- (+10)  
    return (a+b)
```

this is equivalent as define

```
addStuff = \x -> x*2+(x+10)
```

Now if I use the handy way to rewrite the do part, I get

```
addStuff = (*2) >>= \a ->
           (+10) >>= \b ->
           a + b
```

which gives a compiling error. I understand that a, b are Int (or other types of Num), so the last function (\b -> a + b) has type Int -> Int, instead of Int -> Int -> Int.

But does this mean there's not always a way to transform from do to >>= ? Is there any fix to this? Or I'm just using the rule incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem to make the last monadic:

```
addStuff = (*2) >>= \a ->
           (+10) >>= \b ->
           return (a + b)
```

Comment: I see this works. But the point might not be the formatting, but the return, which wraps Int to (Int -> Int). Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

*(you've already been answered, that)* The correct expression must use `return` on the last line:

```
addStuff = (*2) >>= \a ->
           (+10) >>= \b ->
           return (a + b)
```

*(expounding on that, for some clarification)* i.e. `return` is part of a monad definition, not of `do` notation.

Substituting the actual definitions for `((->) r)` monad, it is equivalent to

```
addStuff x 
  = ((\a -> (\b -> return (a + b)) =<< (+10) ) =<< (*2) )  x
  = (\a -> (\b -> return (a + b)) =<< (+10) )  (x*2)  x
  = ( (\b -> return ((x*2) + b)) =<< (+10) )  x
  = (\b -> return ((x*2) + b))  (x+10)  x
  = return ((x*2) + (x+10))  x
  = const  ((x*2) + (x+10))  x
  =         (x*2) + (x+10)
```

as expected. So in general, for functions,

```
do { a <- f ; b <- g ; ... ; n <- h ; return r a b ... n }
```

is the same as

```
\ x -> let a = f x in let b = g x in ... let n = h x in r a b ... n
```

(except that each identifier `a,b,...,n` shouldn't appear in the corresponding function call, because `let` bindings are recursive, and `do` bindings aren't).

The above `do` code is also exactly how `liftM2` is defined in Control.Monad:

```
> liftM2 (+) (*2) (+10) 100
310
```

`liftM_N` for any `N` can be coded with the use of `liftM` and `ap`:

```
> (\a b c -> a+b+c) `liftM` (*2) `ap` (+10) `ap` (+1000) $ 100
1410
```

`liftM` is the monadic equivalent of `fmap`, which for functions is `(.)`, so

```
(+) `liftM` (*2) `ap` (+10) $ x 
  = (+) . (*2) `ap` (+10) $ x 
  = ((+) . (*2)) x ( (+10) x ) 
  = (x*2) + (x+10)
```

because `ap f g x = f x (g x)` for functions (a.k.a. **S**-combinator).